# How to create a header line after text

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, cv

[image: text followed by a header line]

Hi,

I am looking to recreate the style above for a resume. For the heading of sections in the resume, I want the section name (in the example above - Education) to be followed by a header line filling up the rest of the line.

It would be great if someone could tell me how to do it.

Another example is included below. In this one, the text appears in the middle, surrounded by header lines on both sides.

[image: text followed and preceded by header line segments]

Comment: if first case `\hlinefill` can help you, in second — particular `\leaders`.

Comment: I think you should take a look at `mdframed` package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`xhfill`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the other style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}~#1~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If titles are long, then one can use a minipage or variable width (through the varwidth) package, to produce something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newlength\mylen

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {\begin{varwidth}{.7\linewidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Education and other extra activities}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Something analogous can be done for the other style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newlength\mylen

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}
  {\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}~\begin{varwidth}{.75\linewidth}\centering#1\end{varwidth}~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Education and some other extra~activities}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If both styles are to be applied in the same document, define commands for each style ans use them, as many times as required, to switch where needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\Ruled{%
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {\begin{varwidth}{.7\linewidth}\raggedright##1\end{varwidth}~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}
}
\newcommand\Centered{%
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}
  {\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}~\begin{varwidth}{.75\linewidth}\centering##1\end{varwidth}~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}
}

\begin{document}

\Ruled
\section{Education}
\lipsum[4]
\Centered
\section{Education and some other extra~activities}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the settings according to your needs. I didn't use small capitals since some fonts don't support bold-faced small caps.

Comment: last example would look a bit nicer with two words on the last line; adding a `~` (tie) should work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is beautiful. I was ready for a tedious answer, but this is just beautiful.

Comment: A new query - how can I use both the styles in the same document?

Comment: For the time being, I am using both the styles by using one of them to define \section, and the other for \subsection. Can I do better?

Comment: @Soumendra please see the last example in my updated answer.