# Short line for the right side of subsection?

Tags: titles

I want to add a custom short line in the right of my subsection as shown below:
[image: The article I want]

Here is my .tex, how could I add the short blue line in the subsetion right side, and not display in Contents?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 

    \section{section1}
    \subsection{subsection1}
    \lipsum[1]

    \subsection{sub2}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question ... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268397/adding-line-after-section-heading ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of [How to create a header line after text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107594/how-to-create-a-header-line-after-text), [A horizontal line with the same space-filling behaviour as /hfill?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155947/a-horizontal-line-with-the-same-space-filling-behaviour-as-hfill), [how to add number to the title of sections and subsection using the titlesec package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109838/how-to-add-number-to-the-title-of-sections-and-subsection-using-the-titlesec-pac)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}[blue]}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1~\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}[blue]}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 

    \section{section1}
    \subsection{subsection1}
    \lipsum[1]

    \subsection{sub2}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You  obtain the same result without any extra package replacing `\xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}[blue]` with `\color{blue}\titlerule[0.3ex]`.